# Can't figure out this icon on me status bar

Tags: notification-icons

[image][image]
This cross in a circle on top.

Comment: Phone make and model please, plus Android version, is it stock firmware or custom ROM?

Answer (score 0):

Goodday,

This icon appears when data saver has been turned on.
I found this under settings - data usage - "right corner 3dots" - data saver.

Android 8.0.0 OnePlus 3t OxygenOS OpenBeta 17